# What's the advantage of a skycrane system?

Tags: skycrane

Why did Curiosity require a skycrane? It couldnt use a bouncy ball like spirit since it was too big, but why couldnt it land like the viking?

Comment: It did land like the Vikings ... slightly more evolved though. My guess, and it is only a guess, is they may be experimenting with available modes to land a payload( or multiple payload) accurately, and autonomously.